# Set Theory: Conventions Dealing with Quantifiers and Set Builder

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

Let's say I have a set $A=\lbrace x^2|x\in \mathbb{R}\rbrace$. What is more correct to say: option $(1)$, $(2)$, or both are fine?

> $(1)$ If $y\in A$, then $y=x^2$ for some $x\in \mathbb{R}$.
>
> $(2)$ If $y\in A$, then $y=x^2$ and $x\in \mathbb{R}$.

I personally write option $(1)$ all the time in my proofs, but I wonder if that is a bad habit.

---

I know that the set $A$ can also be rewritten as $A=\lbrace  y| y=x^2 \text{ and } x\in \mathbb{R}\rbrace$ too, but I still am unsure what is more correct.

In logic terms, is the following correct?

> $y \in A \leftrightarrow \exists x \in \mathbb R (y = x^2)\leftrightarrow x \in \mathbb R \text{ and } y=x^2$

Comment: Both statements sound good to me - a normal person would understand both correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In answer to your edited question, you **cannot** simply ignore the existential quantifier. While this is a bit picky, it winds up being important down the road to explicitly distinguish between free and bound variables. "$y=x^2\wedge x\in\mathbb{R}$" is not an assertion about *just* $y$, it's an assertion about $y$ *and* $x$; by contrast, "$\exists x(y=x^2\wedge x\in\mathbb{R})$" (or "$\exists x\in\mathbb{R}(y=x^2)$") is just an assertion about $y$ (as desired) since the new variable $x$ is *bound* by the existential quantifier.

Now it is true that in this specific context dropping the "$\exists x$" will probably not lead to confusion, but it is in fact not correct to do so.

Comment: That's what I needed to know. Thank you! I know I am being picky :( Should the set $\lbrace  y| y=x^2 \text{ and } x\in \mathbb{R}\rbrace$ really be rewritten as $\lbrace  y| \exists x\in \mathbb{R} : y=x^2\rbrace$ then too?

Comment: Actually, it should in context to this problem based off what you just said. Thank you again!

Comment: @W.G. Yup, that's right. Basically, every variable in an expression is either *bound* by a quantifier or *free*, in which case you should think of it as an "input" (e.g. $y$ is an "input" in $\{y: ...\}$, since we're defining a predicate *of $y$*). That "input" intuition is of subjective value, so don't focus too hard on it if it's not useful; the point is that every variable must be "accounted for."

Comment: @NoahSchweber $y$ is bound in $\{y\mid\dots\}$. This is a closed term (assuming no other variables are free in the $\dots$). Set comprehension is a binding form, though there are variations on the notation that obscure this, e.g. $\{x^2\mid x\in\mathbb R\}$ means $\{y\mid\exists x\in\mathbb R.y=x^2\}$. In the formulas, $y\in A$ or $\exists x\in\mathbb R.y=x^2$, $y$ is free.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you are basically asking on whether
$$ y \in A \iff \exists x \in \mathbb R (y = x^2)$$
or $$y \in A \iff \exists x (y=x^2 \land x \in \mathbb R)\ .$$

If that is the case you are in luck, because, as long as you are working in the framework of (untyped) classical logic the two statements are equivalent, indeed in general a formula of the form $$\exists x \in A \phi(x)$$ is actually a short hand for $$\exists x (x \in A \land \phi(x))\ .$$

Comment: I edited the question slightly just to avoid confusion. I agree that what you have is equivalent. However, my question is just slightly different. I want to know if I can get rid of the existential quantifier part (i.e. $\exists x$ in your second biconditional down). Is that okay?

Comment: In short, no you cannot drop quatifier. But I see that  Noah's answer address the problem.

Answer (score 0):

All of them are correct.

Your $(1)$

If $y∈A$, then $y=x^2$ for some $x∈R.$ is my preference.